# How do I reinstall npm after stupidly unistall it?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

I'm a newbie and I stupidly uninstalled my version 5.6.0 npm without unistalling my nodejs (version 8.9.4). And when I tried to reinstall the npm, it appears "bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory". I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Any suggestion will be helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

which might reinstall npm.

or ***download and run this script***

https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh

or ***grab it from github***

https://github.com/npm/npm